# 50s/60s short story, written in the form of a letter to an editor, by a girl whose parents are missing in the woods

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My mother talks about this story sometimes, written as a letter to the editor of a fantasy and science fiction magazine from a young girl - she's too young to use the powers, Mama got jealous of Daddy's friendship with the pretty lady living close to them and Mama witched the woods and Daddy can't find his way home. The county is putting in a road, the bulldozer is coming, and she is asking if the editor can do anything to help.

I believe the father traveled through the forest to go to work (maybe in a factory?) And the mother went into the forest to look for the father.

Mom thinks this is from an anthology, or maybe one of the old magazines - I can't tell you how many of the old paperbacks in her house are sci-fi collections that she picked up looking for this story. She probably read this in the 60s - possibly the late 50s. She never said how long the story was, but I'd assume it's only a couple of pages.

Comment: Is that **all** that happened in the story? "My father went into the forest and never came back, then my mother disappeared, and now I hear voices calling from the forest", end of story? Was it a short short story, one page or less? Or is there more to the story but you can't remember (or your mother can't remember) anything else?

Comment: Why did the girl's father go into the forest? Did anyone call the police after the father disappeared? Did the mother also go into the forest, or she just disappeared? Is the little girl living all alone now? The voices she hears, are they her parents' voices, or just voices? What are they saying? ***How long ago did your mother read the story?***

Comment: She probably read this in the 60s. She never said how long the story was, but I'd assume it's only a couple of pages. I believe the father traveled through the forest to go to work (maybe in a factory?) And the mother went into the forest to look for the father. I'll ask her about it and get better details.

Comment: @PetraBorne: :) If you can add those details to the question as you find them?

Comment: Oh. Of course I will.

Comment: I voted to reopen this because there's a good bunch of "unique" details: the story as a letter to an editor, timeframe, characters described...